# Prove that H(s) = G(!s) is a CPRNG if G(s) is one

Tags: random-number-generator

Given a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator $G$, prove that $H$ with $H(s) = G(!s)$ is also a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator. Here $s$ is a binary string; $!s$ is its complement.

For this we have to prove the two properties of a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator: the expansion and the pseudo-randomness.

The expansion is trivial to prove, because that's the same for $H$ and $G$. How can we prove that it is also cryptographically pseudo-random?

Comment: Assume someone could break $H$. Show how this would result in a break of $G$. This is a contradiction since $G$ is cryptographically secure. Therefore, $H$ must be cryptographically secure also. This is a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction). Or, if it is easier, formulate it as a [proof by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive).

Comment: I've tried and failed. I don't know how to show that breaking G(!s) results in breaking G(s).

Comment: Say you want to break $G(s)$, well, feed $H$ with $!s$. $H(!s)=G(!!s)=G(s)$. Therefore, you've broken $G(s)$ since you can break $H$.

Comment: So the proof is to first argument why !s is evenly distributed if s is evenly distributed and then follow that H(!s) can be broken, because we assumed so, and therefor G(s) can be broken. And that's a contradiction to G(s) being secure, so our assumption (that H is insecure) must be wrong, thus H is secure.

Comment: Is the security of G contingent upon $s$ being evenly distributed? If not, then you don't need to state that. Other than that possible change, looks good.

Comment: Formatted question. If anybody knows how to best code a binary complement in Tex please edit it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof by contradiction seems most appropriate here.

Assume that $H$ is not cryptographically secure. This means it fails to provide at least one of the properties of a CSPRNG as defined in your class, textbook, whatever. Then you must show how you can use an attack on $H$ to attack the cryptographic security of $G$. To do this, note that $H(!s)=G(!!s)=G(s)$. Since $G$ is cryptographically secure, your assumption must be incorrect. Therefore, you can conclude that $H$ is in fact cryptographically secure.

Comment: A proof by contradiction seems unnecessarily complicated here.  It's enough to observe that for uniformly random $s$, the distribution of $t=!s$ is also uniform.  So $H(s)$ and $G(t)$ are identically distributed, and the latter is pseudorandom because $t$ is uniform.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert True. For some reason, proof by contradiction has always been may favorite. You know what they say, when you have a hammer...